# Powerpoint VBA Loop all slides, check title, if correct title, paste shapes to another presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Goal:
-Loop through presentation checking each slide for a certain title
-Once title is found
-Copy the shapes for the charts and footnote
-Then paste them into a separate presentation.

Notes:
-The slides in the presentations don't have titles but are located at Shapes(1)
-I receive a

> run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of
>   range.

-This error occurs on the line of the If statement

```
Sub library_update()

Dim NTppt As Presentation
Set NTppt = Application.Presentations("Z:\NTPath\NLibrary.pptx")

Dim ppt As Presentation
Set ppt = Application.Presentations("Z:\NTPath\Library.pptm")

Dim sld as slide

For Each sld In NTppt.Slides
        If sld.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Fixed Income - Yield Curves" Then
            With NTppt
                sld.Shapes.Range(Array(2, 3)).Copy
                ppt.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
            End With
        End If
Next sld

End Sub
```

[image: Powerpoint slide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below worked. I am not sure why my code produced the original run time error but I assume it has something to do with not finding shapes(1) in some of my powerpoint slides.

To fix the problem, I searched for "Fixed Income - Yield Curves" in all shapes of all slides.

```
Sub library_update()

Dim NTppt As Presentation
Set NTppt = Application.Presentations("Z:\NTPath\NLibrary.pptx")

Dim ppt As Presentation
Set ppt = Application.Presentations("Z:\NTPath\Library.pptm")

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In NTppt.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txt_range = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            'Confirm exact spelling and capitalization of the slides or an error will return
            If txt_range = "Fixed Income – Yield Curves" Then
                With NTppt
                    sld.Shapes.Range(Array(2, 3)).Copy
                    ppt.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld


End Sub
```